# ¿Cómo hago para comparar las contraseñas del registro en mi web con crypt()?

Tags: php

Hola a todos desde Cuba soy bastante novato en `php` y tengo una duda sobre un pequeño sistema que estoy montando. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para comparar las contraseñas del registro en mi web con `crypt()`?

---

Hasta ahora tengo esto, pero no q esta mal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Bueno lo q hasta ahora tengo el lo siguiente:

```
<$php
//conecto con la BD
require ('cnx.php');
//datos del formulario
$Name =$_POST["nombR"];
$User =$_POST["emailR"];
$Pass =$_POST["passR"];
$RPas =$_POST["RepassR"];
/*encripto la contraseña generando una clave aleatoria*/
function aleatoriedad(){
$caracteres ="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789";
$nueva_clave ="";
for($i=1; $i<34; $i++){
$nueva_clave =$caracteres [rand(1,34)];
}
return $nueva_clave;
}
//obtener valor aleatorio desde la función
$aleatorio=aleatoriedad ();
$valor ="07";
$salt ="$2y$".$valor."$".$aleatorio."$";
$PassC =crypt($salt, $Pass);
$RPasC =crypt($salt, Rpas);
/*al hacer un echo en esta parte de las variables $PassC y $RPasC me muestra los 2 parámetros iguales pero con muy pocos caracteres */
If ($PassC == $RPasC){
$data ="INSERT INTO usuarios (id, user, passw, nombr, roles) values (NULL, $User, $Pass, $Name, 'usuario')";
if (!$result =mysqli_query ($conn, $data)){
die('Ya existe ese usuario');
}
else{
die('Proceso exitoso' );
}}
else{
die('Las contraseñas no coinciden');
}
$>
```

Eso es todo lo q tengo hasta ahora del formulario de registro. cada ves q intento crear un usuario me dice q ya existe. mi duda es la sgte sera xq el Hash q se genera con la función crypt es muy corto y debido a eso no me deja continuar o sera que lo he estado haciendo de una manera incorrecta. Gracias a todos y disculpen las molestias.

Comment: agrega lo que llevas

Comment: Hola Alexsandrov Music, deberías poner el código en modo texto en lugar de como una imagen, de ese modo será más fácil de leer e identificar el problema. Además, sería ideal que explicases qué es exactamente lo que no funciona; ya estás usando `crypt`, ¿recibes algún error? ¿no hace lo que esperas? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui un ejemplo de un login.

```
   //Toma los datos del form de login
    $email = $_POST["user"];
    $pass = $_POST["pass"];

    //Donde $pass es lo que se ha ingresado en el form y $password es el nombre de la tabla en la DB
    $encript = crypt($pass, $password);

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$encript' ";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($connection, $consulta) or die(mysql_error());
    $datos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
```

Seria genial si agregas el codigo de tu form. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias amigo lo probare y tratare de incluir código para la próxima

Comment: Esta respuesta no debería usarse porque presenta vulnerabilidades graves de seguridad (en particular problemas de inyección SQL). Por ejemplo, si el "user" pasado es `' or 1=1;--` se validará el login a pesar de no haber dado un usuario/contraseña válido.